# UIDocumentInteractionController always creates a copy

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm currently developing a Xamarin.iOS App that gets a document from a web service that should then be edited offline on the tablet after being downloaded to the internal storage.

The most common answer was to use the `UIDocumentInteractionController`. However if I use the `UIDocumentInteractionController` then I can only create a copy of my original file and open this copy. To get it back into my app I have to make the user select the document from the 'UIDocumentPickerViewController'. 
Is there a better way to make the `UIDocumentInteractionController' not create and open a copy of the original, or to at least get the url from the new documentcopy?

Code to open the file:

```
public void OpenFile()
{
    var url = NSUrl.FromFilename(FilePath);

    var controller = new UIDocumentInteractionController();
    controller.Url = url;
    controller.PresentOpenInMenu(table.Frame, table, true);
}
```

If that is not Possible: Are there different tools or controlls i could use to open and edit a MS-Office file directly?

Comment: I know that Google Drive allows "Open In" for MS-Office apps. If you are trying to custom implement that, did you try to use Telerik/Syncfusion?

Comment: I tried Google Drive, but it also shows to copy the file, maybe there is a Flag somewhere else that can disable the copy?
I have looked at Telerik but they do not have anything for my Problem in Xamarin.iOS. For Syncfusion i haven't found anything from a googlesearch that could solve my Problem, could you maybe give me a name for the controll?

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/word-framework/xamarin/word-libraryhere you go. Also, what all file extensions are you specifically talking about? XLS, PPT, PDF?

Comment: Thank you very much, i will give it a try. I am mainly trying to edit DOC and DOCX files, XLS, XLSX and PPT would also be useful, but not required.

Comment: I have tried the syncfusion controlls for Xamarin.iOS, but it seems that i can only create and edit the document in code or by creating my own editor. To open the file I stille need to use the UIDocumentInteractionController which has the original Problem.

Comment: @Groknost You can't modify the original files on iCloud. You can only get the copy then upload the new files to the iCloud drive.